# Live video streaming webrtc?

Tags: html, webrtc

So I want to be able to let one client distribute live video feed to alot of other clients only watching. Is it possible to use WebRTC for this? Or will I basically have to go through a service like ustream or whatever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It *is* possible, with a caveat. One client can establish many outgoing P2P connections to every viewer and stream video to them directly. However, for more than a very small handful of viewers this will quickly saturate the origin's bandwidth and possibly CPU. You would not be able to serve many viewers this way; however this would work entirely without middleman.*

<sub>* Safe for the WebRTC connection negotiation server.</sub>

To be able to serve a larger number of viewers you'll have to use a centralised distribution server. The source would send exactly one video stream to that server, and the server would stream it to anyone who's interested. This still requires that server to have a beefy CPU and a lot of bandwidth; but this is more realistic to scale than the client side.

You may need to spend a lot of money on such a server; have a look at c3.xlarge and better instances at [AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/) to get an idea. Using an established, cheap infrastructure like ustream may indeed be the more realistic option.